# Нужна ли запятая перед ИЛИ, если предложение вопросительное?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, ссп

Нужна ли запятая перед ИЛИ, если предложение вопросительное?
Пример: *Действительно ли старые обиды забываются или мы только прячем их в душе с прошествием времени?*

Comment: а точно нужна запятая перед "перед" в заголовке вопроса?

Answer (score 8):

Нет, не нужна: запятая перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *«и»*), *или, либо* не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения выражены двумя вопросительными предложениями ([источник информации](http://www.lingvotech.com/znakssp)).

Answer (score 4):

Относительно союза ИЛИ есть и другие мнения. В частности, в книге "Серия: СОВРЕМЕННЫЙ РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК, Е.М. Ткаченко ПУНКТУАЦИЯ: правила, упражнения, диктанты Часть 2" указано, что  запятая ставится, так как союз ИЛИ способствует членению предложения на две части (о чем свидетельствует пауза между ними): "Дядя в вас влюблен, или нет"? "Ты меня понял, или ударить тебя?"

Сравнить (для союза И): "Отчего в этом призыве чистой души послышалась мне печаль и мое сердце так болезненно сжалось?" Здесь явно отсутствует пауза между простыми предложениями.

В то же время другие источники предполагают отсутствие запятой при наличии обоих союзов (И/ ИЛИ),  предпочитая не разбираться в интонационных тонкостях. Это как раз та простота (или примитивность), к которой мы стремимся.

Answer (score 2):

I. Запятая перед «или» ставится, если «ли… или» соединяют части сложного предложения, в том числе вопросительного.

1. Было ли последнее явление счастливой случайностью, или же действительно жизнь начинает подаваться в сторону тех, кто желал бы вывести ее на дорогу разумности, – во всяком случае, это приятно и дает надежду, что дикая связь университетской Татьяны с винной монополией и Яром будет наконец разрушена. Л. Андреев, Москва.
2. Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или, просто, по своей охоте гуляете по лесам да дерете прохожих? Н. Гоголь, Мертвые души.
3. В ней сердце долго ли страдало, или скоро слез прошла пора? (Пушкин);

II. Союзы ли…или рассматриваются как повторяющиеся, и придаточные части сложноподчиненного предложения, связанные этими союзами, разделяются запятой:

1. И долго все присутствовавшие оставались в недоумении, не зная, действительно ли они видели эти необыкновенные глаза, или это была просто мечта… (Г.);
2. …Налево всё небо над горизонтом было залито багровым заревом, и трудно было понять, был ли то где-нибудь пожар, или же собиралась всходить луна (Ч.);
3. После этого решится, будет ли он воевать, летать, жить, или ему будут вечно уступать место в трамвае и провожать его сочувственными взглядами (Пол.).
4. Трудно было понять, наступают ли это сумерки, или это тучи так непроницаемо               окутали землю (Баб.).
5. Слышался ли в открытые окна трезвон городских и монастырских колоколов, кричал ли во дворе павлин, или кашлял кто-нибудь в передней, всем невольно приходило на ум, что Михаил Ильич серьезно болен (Чехов).
6. После разговора с князем Андреем Пьер размышляет, станет ли он по-прежнему придерживаться масонских позиций, или надо принять взгляды друга на жизнь.

III. Запятая не ставится, если ли… или соединяют однородные члены предложения:

1.Поддержит ли он меня или не поддержит?

2. Нехлюдов понял это слово и этот взгляд так, что она хочет знать, держится ли он своего решения или принял её отказ и изменил его (Л.Т.);

3.Уездный чиновник пройди мимо - я уже и задумался, куда он идет: на вечер ли к какому-нибудь своему брату или прямо к себе домой (Гоголь).

IV.Запятая ставится между частями с союзами ли…или, раскрывающими содержание общей подчиняющей части: Оставался ещё не решённым вопрос: начнёт ли батальон Сабурова марш к Сталинграду, или же, после ночёвки, утром сразу двинется весь полк (Сим.);

Примечание. Союзы ли... или не всегда являются повторяющимися. Так, в предложении 
И не понять, смеется ли Матвей Карев над своими словами или над тем, как заглядывают ему в рот студенты (Фед.) союз ли вводит изъяснительную придаточную часть, а союз или соединяет однородные члены.

Следовательно, запятая не ставится, если ли…или  соединяют однородные члены предложения, и ставится, если они соединяют части предложения.

Comment: "Плохо ли вам было у Плюшкина, или, просто, по своей охоте гуляете по лесам да дерете прохожих? Н. Гоголь, Мертвые души." - а зачем "просто" выделено запятыми? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Присоединяюсь к ответу Noir. Если части сложносочиненного предложения что-то объединяет (общий второстепенный член, вводной слово, общее придаточное, общая интонация), то запятая перед союзами И, ИЛИ не ставится. В данном случае объединяющий элемент - это вопросительная интонация.

См. справочник по орфографии и пунктуации под ред.Лопатина. Параграф 112

[здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Comment: Лопатин: «Где будет собрание и кто его председатель? — общая вопросительная интонация». Но вот примеров с союзом ИЛИ Лопатин не приводит, хотя на интонацию ссылается. Но объединяющая интонация присутствует в предложениях с союзом И, и ее нет в предложениях с союзом ИЛИ. И еще интересный момент. В случае с союзом И  первое предложение может быть невопросительным, например: "Мы расстаемся, и почему бы нам не сказать правду друг другу?". В этом случае наличие или отсутствие запятой меняет смысл сказанного. А есть ли такой вариант для союза ИЛИ?

Comment: "Лопатин (интонационное ударение на "Лопатин") будет проводить собрание, или он ещё на больничном?" (после слова "собрание" можно поставить вопросительный знак. А можно - запятую!). В приведённом примере "Лопатин: "Где будет собрание, и кто его председатель?" запятая нужна, если следовать этому принципу. "Мы квиты или я ещё что-то должен тебе?" (по поводу запятой сомневаюсь)

Comment: Я имела в ввиду "у Лопатина", то есть пример взят из его правил.
А как вы напишите следующие предложения (в соответствии с правилами Лопатина или без соответствия): (1)Мы не квиты ()и кое-что ты мне должен.(2)Мы не квиты ()и кое-что ты мне должен! Эти два предложения (утвердительное и восклицательное) тоже связаны по смыслу.

Comment: Предложение (1): уверенно поставлю запятую. Предложение (2)(в особенности, если оно усилено ещё двумя восклицательными знаками): следует поставить угрожающее тире (но я не автор этого предложения; что поставите Вы, я не знаю)... Я считаю, что Синий Филолог прав.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая перед союзом "или" нужна обязательно, никого не слушайте и ставьте смело: это сложносочинённое предложение, состоящее из двух простых, двусоставных (то есть в каждом есть подлежащее и сказуемое), объединённых союзом "или".

Comment: А каким будет первое простое по цели высказывания? Лучше бы это были два отдельных предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю, бесспорно, поздновато, но суть дела это не меняет. Во-первых, в данном предложении  два простых предложения с двумя предикативными основами, соединёнными сочинительным союзом *ИЛИ*. Да, запятая в ССП ставится, если союз *ИЛИ* соединяет две предикативные основы.

Например, рассмотрим такое предложение:

> Приходи, или я тебя убью.

Прошу прошение за плохой пример - в голову сразу же это пришло. В данном случае союз имеет значение *в противном случае*. Звучит очень похоже. А теперь предлагаю рассмотреть две предикативные основы данного сложносочиненного предложения. Первая: [Приходи]. Данное простое предложение является неполным двусоставным (субъект нам понятен из контекста). Это определённо-личное односоставное предложение, в котором главным членом предложения является сказуемое, выраженное глаголом в повелительном наклонении. Можно также изменить предложение на более вежливый оттенок и вообще полностью изменить предложение (без изменения синтаксической структуры).

> Приходите, или я Вас убью.

В данном случае все равно первая предикативная основа является односоставной (определённо-личное), глагол выражен повелительным наклонением во множественным числе (формообразующий суффикс *ТЕ*).

В таких случаях, безусловно, постановка запятой требуется.

Теперь давайте рассмотрим предложения, аналогичные Вашему.

Итак, поехали.

> Действительно ли старые обиды забываются или мы только прячем их в душе с прошествием времени?

Предикативные основы: [обиды забываются] и [мы прячем].

Если сложносочиненное предложение является вопросительным, восклицательным или же побудительным, то запятая не требуется.

> Когда у него будет день рождения и что он хочет в качестве подарка?

Это аналог Вашего предложения.

Answer (score -1):

По правилам, конечно, запятой там не может быть, никаких оговорок для вопросительных предложения в правилах нет.
Но знаете, это, похоже, тот редкий случай, когда пунктуацию хочется оформить вопреки правилам. Или, вернее сказать, найти в правилах хоть малейшее основание для отступления от общего принципа.
К сожалению, источники, на которые ссылаются в предыдущих ответах нельзя признать достаточно авторитетными для окончательного разрешения спора.

Comment: Ну как же нет в правилах. Вы уже по этому вопросу высказывали свое сомнение, а я давала цитату из Лопатина и ссылку.

Comment: > К сожалению, источники, на которые ссылаются в предыдущих ответах нельзя признать достаточно авторитетными для окончательного разрешения спора.

Ах, если бы ответы на все вопросы можно было найти в авторитетных источниках...

Comment: Авторитетные источники стали бы еще авторитетнее, если бы объясняли свои правила-образцы. Кстати, в правилах 1956 года об объединяющей интонации речи нет (там только общий второстепенный член и общее придаточное предложение), зато причина указана - обозначение тесной связи предложений. Но вот при наличии союза ИЛИ  вопросительная интонация вряд ли создает такую тесную связь.

Comment: Я осваивал пунктуацию по Розенталю и помню, что у него есть точное указание на вопросительные предложения.

Comment: Розенталь составлял свои учебники на основе Правил 1956 года - кстати, кандидат фил. наук и зам. гл. редактора журнала "Русский язык в школе" Д.Э. Розенталь принимал участие в  подготовке свода к печати. Розенталь применил основные принципы Правил к решению конкретных орфографических задач, и его школа является наиболее авторитетной. Но это не значит, что все его решения непогрешимы и должны считаться абсолютной истиной. Русская пунктуация основана на трех принципах, и в данном случае нарушается смысловой и интонационный принципы (нет тесной связи предложений, и есть пауза в речи).