# Пунктуация в вопросительном ССП

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

Предложение из Нацкорпуса:

**Что свойственно такому обществу, и почему именно тогда бурное развитие получил кредит?** [В. В. Солодников, Д. Г. Цыбикова. Особенности потребительского кредита в России // «Вестник РАН», 2009]

По [Розенталю](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/48.htm) запятая между двумя вопросительными предложениями не ставится.
В предложении ошибка или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Не буду оформлять как ответ, но считаю, что запятой не должно быть. Оба предложения вопросительные.

Answer (score 3):

Нашлась нужная [**научная статья**](http://naukarus.com/osobennosti-potrebitelskogo-kredita-v-rossii), нашлось и предложение в ней:

*...термин "общество массового потребления" принадлежит американскому социологу и экономисту У. Ро-стоу. Что свойственно такому обществу, и почему именно тогда бурное развитие получил кредит?*

1. Американского социолога и экономиста зовут *Уолт Уитмен Ростоу* (англ. Walt Whitman Rostow; одна из транскрипций имени — В. В. Ростоу).
2. Думаю, что и в "нашем" предложении присутствует ошибка: не нужна здесь запятая.

Пересмотрела достаточно источников ([***Лопатин***](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=358), [***Online-библиотека***](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/733-12_znaki_prepinaniya_v_slozhnosochinennyh_predlozheniyah.html), [***narod.ru***](http://raal100.narod.ru/index/0-63)), и везде одно: запятая перед одиночным союзом "и" не ставится, если в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят вопросительные предложения(о степени их распространенности нигде не говорится).

***Что свойственно такому обществу и почему именно тогда бурное развитие получил кредит?***
Что такое Троицкая родительская суббота и что нужно делать в этот день?
Зачем же Пушкин придает "Капитанской дочке" форму мемуаров частного человека и как эта форма соотносится с жанром этого произведения?

Подобная ситуация (только с союзом "или") уже рассматривалась на форуме:
[**Нужна ли запятая перед ИЛИ, если предложение вопросительное?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30469/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Comment: Может быть, распространенность и не имеет принципиального значения, но вот тематика вопросов важна. Если вопросы близко связаны по содержанию и на них можно дать один распространенный ответ, то вопросы читаются одной фразой, пауза не делается, запятая не ставится. Если это  темы,  которые надо раскрывать последовательно, то они должны читаться раздельно (как два вопроса, а не один), то тогда пауза делается и запятая ставится.

Comment: Так что выбирает автор: с одной стороны надо писать по правилам, а с другой - представлять, как реально будет читаться его текст. Если его устраивает чтение "на одном дыхании", то запятая однозначно не ставится.

Comment: Честно скажу: и мне тоже хочется поставить запятую! Но в правилах всё так категорично, без всяких исключений, интерпретаций или вариаций: не нужна - и всё тут!

Answer (score 2):

По формальным правилам запятая  между двумя вопросительными предложениями не ставится, например: **Неужели впереди болото и путь к отступлению отрЕзан?**

Здесь **два нераспространенных предложения объединены в одну вопросительную фразу**. Они связаны причинно-следственными отношениями, нет паузы и  запятой. Это классический случай применения правила.

**ЧтО свойственно такому обществу, и почему именно тОгда бурное развитие получил кредит?**

А вот в заданном предложении темы вопросов разные, предложения распространенные, в одну фразу их не объединишь. Там явно присутствую два ударения, это две фразы, поэтому пауза необходима.  И еще вопрос: вопросительная интонация - это повышение голоса в конце предложения, а на каком слове будем его повышать?

**Поэтому формальное правило сюда не подходит**. По-хорошему надо бы в правилах указать  исключения, когда невозможно интонационное объединение, но в правилах этого нет.

Поэтому решение за автором, все риски он берет на себя.

Comment: _Arina: **Неужели впереди болото и путь к отступлению отрЕзан?**
Здесь **два нераспространенных предложения**…_ === А почему **нераспространённых-то**? Разве "к отступлению" не определение?

Comment: Я имела в виду предложения мало распространенные, небольшого объема, такие,  что  их можно произнести как одну фразу.