# Можно ли поставить запятую в сложном вопросительном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, и

**Является ли это грубой ошибкой, и как об этом следует рассуждать в трёхголосии?**

В данном предложении две грамматические основы, но каждое из простых предложений повествует об одной и той же ошибке, и второе простое предложение вводит новый контекст для этой ошибки (трёхголосие), словно делая её значение шире.
Этот фактор, а также то, что предложение вопросительное, не могут влиять на постановку запятой (не требовать её)?

Comment: Придать фразе вид цитаты, или просто выделить как-либо, не помешало бы.

Answer (score 4):

[Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=358)
В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами *и, да* (в значении «и»), *или, либо* **запятая не ставится** в следующих случаях:
5) если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: *Где будет собрание **и** кто его председатель?* — общая вопросительная интонация...

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133)
3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:
1) в о п р о с и т е л ь н ы е предложения: *Это кто такие и что им надобно?* (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; *Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?*

**Является ли это грубой ошибкой и как об этом следует рассуждать в трёхголосии?**

Это сложносочиненное предложение. Оба простых предложения в его составе являются вопросительными (то есть общей для них является вопросительная интонация). Об этом говорят вопросительная частица **ли** в первом предложении и вопросительное слово **как** — во втором.
Вывод — **запятая перед "и" не нужна.**

P. S. Есть особое мнение по поводу постановки запятой перед "и". Если интересно, посмотрите здесь:
[Пунктуация в вопросительном ССП](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433624/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%9F/433642#433642).