# Прямая речь — в строку или с абзаца?

Tags: грамматика, прямая-речь, диалог

*Марк одною левой рукой, легко, как пустой мешок, вздернул на воздух упавшего, поставил его на ноги и заговорил гнусаво, плохо выговаривая арамейские слова: «Римского прокуратора называть — игемон. Других слов не говорить. Смирно стоять. Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя?»
Арестованный пошатнулся, но совладал с собою, краска вернулась, он перевел дыхание и ответил хрипло: «Я понял тебя. Не бей меня».*

Итак, бессмертный роман Булгакова. Я писал диктант по данному роману. И мой вариант был таков:

*Марк одною левой рукой, легко, как пустой мешок, вздернул на воздух упавшего, поставил его на ноги и заговорил гнусаво, плохо выговаривая арамейские слова:

— Римского прокуратора называть — игемон. Других слов не говорить. Смирно стоять. Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя?

Арестованный пошатнулся, но совладал с собою, краска вернулась, он перевел дыхание и ответил хрипло:

— Я понял тебя. Не бей меня.*

Знаю, что был неправ. Но в художественных книгах встречаются и такой вариант, ведь так? И как тогда быть? Ну, например, если я опять же пишу диктант. А может, в таких случаях допускается двоякое толкование?

Comment: Бека, к Вам встречный вопрос. Как Вы пришли к решению поставить запятую в предложении: "Ты понял меня, или ударить тебя?" (У автора она есть, но это нестандартное решение).

Comment: Я обнаружил там две грамматические основы: "Ты понял" и "ударить". Поэтому представил как ССП.

Comment: На самом деле все не так просто (см. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30469/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%98%d0%9b%d0%98-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет косвенной речи, а лишь два варианта прямой. Если закрыть на это глаза и сформулировать Ваш вопрос правильными терминами, то ответ на него будет двойным:

1) Не имеет значения, как оформлять прямую речь в своём тексте. Это на усмотрение автора.

2) Булгаков уже написал так, как лучше на его усмотрение, — диалогом. Вам следует придерживаться написания в первоисточнике. В каждом издании воспроизводится только такой, авторский вариант.