# Нужна ли в данном случае запятая перед "или"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Была это мистическая причина(,) или же что-то более обыденное, но не менее беспощадное?

Нужна ли запятая и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Была это мистическая причина, или же (было) что-то более обыденное, но не менее беспощадное?**

Запятая ставится **в сложносочиненном предложении**.

Это не однородные члены по следующим признакам: в первом предложении согласование подлежащего и сказуемого в ж.р. (была причина), а во втором предложение согласование в ср.роде подлежащего ***что-то*** и однородных определений.

Второе предложение неполное (пропущено сказуемое ***было***).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (про вопросительную интонацию)**

**В случае союза И** предложение легко читается в одну фразу  с повышением тона в конце (общая вопросительная интонация): **Неужели впереди болото и путь к отступлению отрЕзан?;**

**В случае союза ИЛИ** предложение плохо читается в одну фразу: **Ты пОнял меня или удАрить тебя?** Почему? Да потому что там два ударения, два вопроса, две ситуации, которые нужно обозначить. Нет у них общей вопросительной интонации.

И совсем не читается в одну фразу предложение с союзом ИЛИ, если простое предложение осложнено однородными членами: **Была это мистИческая причина, или же (было) что-то более обЫденное, но не менее беспощАдное?**

В этом случае ударение падает на каждый из однородных членов. И вот попробуйте всё это прочитать без обозначения тона, вряд ли у вас что-нибудь получится.

**Поэтому делаются попытки отредактироать это правило, но, вероятно, безуспешные.** Потому что для нас знаки препинания – это не "нотные знаки" (как для Паустовского), помогающие читать текст, а формальная расстановка их по правилам. Смысл этих правил не очень ясен, да только кому он сейчас нужен, этот смысл.

Материал по теме: [Нужна ли запятая перед ИЛИ, если предложение вопросительное?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30469/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, запятая не нужна.

Если считать предложение простым, то запятая не нужна.

Если считать предложение сложносочиненным, то действует правило: если обе части сложносочиненного предложения являются вопросительными предложениями, запятая   не нужна.

Comment: Страница из Розенталя (Розенталь, Русский язык. Орфография и пунктуация, М. 2017, с 179) в подтверждение: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=VY2LAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA179&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=bZ1qmiM8cp&sig=ACfU3U3lib-pNssHRYmOQAG928wh5jMMfQ&w=1280 но->то