# Нужна ли запятая перед «и» и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Напишите мне в WhatsApp или Telegram(,) и я свяжусь с Вами в ближайшее время.

Answer (score 4):

***Напишите мне в WhatsApp или Telegram, и я свяжусь с Вами в ближайшее время.***

Запятая перед «и» нужна. Предложение сложносочиненное. В его состав входят два простых предложения, в каждом из которых своя основа: ***[Вы] напишите***, ***я свяжусь***.

См.: [**§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении**](https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=133)

Comment: Может быть, стоит сказать, что первое предложение односоставное, сказуемое выражено повелительной формой глагола.

Comment: @Sharon  Да, я думал об этом, спасибо. Теперь и комментария достаточно.

Comment: Пжста, переведите. Какого комментария?

Comment: @Sharon Вашего.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна (хотя в некоторых подобных случаях лучше использовать тире), уже ответили (Александр Стрелец), добавить непосредственно по вопросу нечего.

Я больше не для автора, но для местных любителей головоломок.

Есть случай, когда ничем более непримечательные конструкции ССП запятой не требуют. Я не про общие члены - и подобное, это все более к СПП относится.

Я про ССП вопросительные и восклицательные.
Вот есть такой вопрос
[Нужна ли запятая перед ИЛИ, если предложение вопросительное?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30469)
Там есть в ответе (tangrix) такая фраза, которую в разных вариантах очень любят повторять при обсуждениях ССП.

> Если сложносочиненное предложение является вопросительным,
> восклицательным или же побудительным, то запятая не требуется.

К несчастью, ссылки там нет, а непосредственно Правила-56 о таком не знают. Говорили о Розентале, но у него именно такой формулировки тоже нет. Тем не менее попробуем включить такую рекомендацию в рассмотрение.
Коль скоро в этой формулировке есть упоминание "побудительных предложений", то кто может поручиться, что разбираемое ССП не состоит из двух побудительных?!

Если так, то некоторые основания для исключения запятой все-таки имеются.

*ПС. Пишу в порядке обсуждения, а то что-то часто стали мои опусы воспринимать как императивы, каковымы, они, естественно не являются,  и категорически с ними не соглашаться.*